# Регулярные выражения в PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Монстры регулярных выражений, здравствуйте! Прошу вашей помощи:
Есть строка $xxx. Нужно записать в массив ВСЕ строки, которые находятся между

`<a href="/catalogue/` и `/" title`

По просьбе [[@nmd](/users/15440/nmd)](/users/15440/nmd) дополняю вопрос:
Строка, в которой дложен производиться поиск это HTML код большой такого вида:

```
<li>
<a href="/catalogue/foundation/associations/" title="Индустриальные объединения и некоммерческие партнёрства">
Ассоциации и союзы
<small class="pull-right">16</small></a>
</li>
```

Нужно записать в массив все строки, которые находятся между `<a href="/catalogue/` и `/" title`
В данном примере ответом был бы массив с единственным элементом: `foundation/associations`

А вообще должен быть массив с кучей элементов итого.
Благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Для монстров регулярных выражений, думаю, стоит написать текст, из которого происходит выборка, и что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Так http://regex101.com/r/iF5sR5/1?
ой, не так сейчас подправлю

Вот
http://regex101.com/r/iF5sR5/2

Comment: @NMD, значит, регулярное выражение получается вот это:

    <a href="\/catalogue\/(.*)\/" title

Верно?

Comment: Именно так.

Comment: @NMD, тогда поясните мне, пожалуйста, что делаю не так:

    preg_match_all('<a href="\/catalogue\/(.*)\/" title', $str, $rez);

Comment: Зайди по ссылке http://regex101.com/r/iF5sR5/2 , нажми слева кнопочку code generator и там увидишь, в чем разница.  
Необходимо экранировать кавычки "

не могу больше комментить))
В общем, смотри, как работать с группами регулярок в PHP:  
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php
4 пример для тебя.

Comment: @NMD Так, почти разобрался. Только мне нужно то, что находится МЕЖДУ теми строками, а не вместе с ними. Вот мой код:

    $readfilearray = file("htmlcode01.txt");
    foreach ($readfilearray as $k => $v) {
     $re = "/<a href=\"\\/catalogue\\/(.*)\\/\" title/"; 
     $str = $v;
     preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
     var_dump($matches[0]);
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?<=<a href=\"\\/catalogue\\/).*(?=\\/\" title)/
```